# How to concatenate pandas dataframe date and different time formats to single timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, string-to-datetime

I have two columns in a `pandas` data frame as outlined below. Notice how some of the `EVENT_TIME` is in `hh.mm.ss`, some is in `hh:mm:ss AM/PM` format.

[image]

**When running...**

```
import pandas

df['EVENT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EVENT_DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')

print(df['EVENT_DATE'])
```

...I can get `EVENT_DATE` in a consumable (for my purposes) format (e.g. `1999-07-28`).

**But when running...**

```
df['EVENT_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EVENT_TIME'], format='%H.%M.%S', errors='coerce')
df['EVENT_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EVENT_TIME'], format='%I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')

print(df['EVENT_TIME'])
```

**...`1900-01-01` is added to the times and is not being applied to all rows.**

```
1900-01-01 16:40:00
1900-01-01 15:55:00
1900-01-01 14:30:00
1900-01-01 13:26:00
NaT
NaT
NaT
NaT
```

How do I concatenate the date and times (which include multiple time formats) in a single timestamp?

**Edit1:**

**@Wen-Ben 's solution got me here:**

```
1      19:53:00
11     14:30:00
15     16:30:00
```

**Then to concatenate EVENT_DATE and EVENT_TIME, I found this (which works):**

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['EVENT_DATE'], r['EVENT_TIME']),1)
```

**...results in:**

```
1     1999-07-28 19:53:00
11    2001-07-28 14:30:00
15    2002-06-07 16:30:00
```

**Next I want to get this into ISO8601 format. So I found this (which works):**

```
pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP']).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H:%M%SZ'))
```

**...results in:**

```
1      19990728T19:5300Z
11     20010728T14:3000Z
15     20020607T16:3000Z
```

**HERES MY NEW PROBLEM:**

Running `print(TIMESTAMP)` still shows the concatenated versions (e.g. `1999-07-28 19:53:00`) instead of the ISO version (e.g.`19990728T19:5300Z`)

**How do I get the ISO8601 column "added" to the dataframe?**

Ideally, I want it to take the place of `TIMESTAMP`. I want it as a transformation of the data, not tacked on as a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fillna`

```
s1=pd.to_datetime(df['EVENT_TIME'], format='%H.%M.%S', errors='coerce')
s2=pd.to_datetime(df['EVENT_TIME'], format='%I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')
df['EVENT_TIME']=s1.fillna(s2)
```

Comment: Thank you @Wen-Ben. This did indeed work and gives me another tool to use in the future.